# Golang обернуть тело запроса в одинарные кавычки

Tags: postgresql, http, golang

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста,есть приложение,которое принимает запросы по http и преобразует его к соответствующей функции в postgres. При post-запросе в урле передается один числовой параметр,другой передается в теле запроса в виде json. Вопрос такой : postgres принимает json в одинарных кавычках, как реализовать "оборачивание" тела запроса в одинарные кавычки или принято передавать в теле запроса json уже в них?

П.С. Пробовал и с помощью функций  replace пакетов bytes и string, пробовал с помощью append,но мне кажется, что это все как-то проще реализуется)

вот как подставляю значения

```
rows, err := db.Query("Select * from test.user_comment_ins($1,$2)", userID, body)
```

где body - данные из POST-запроса:

```
curl -d {"txt":"cheers"} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/user/5/comment/
```

если же отправляю его с одинарными кавычками,то все проходит и возвращается результат  POST-запроса:

```
curl -d '{"txt":"cheers"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:80/api/v1/user/5/comment/
```

может суть в том, что изначально второй вариант - стандарт отправки json, или же нужно производить какие-нибудь манипуляции?

Comment: А зачем json оборачивать в кавычки ? Не хотите ли вы сказать, что подставляете переменную с данными непосредственно в текст запроса ? Так не надо делать никогда (если конечно не хотите что бы вас взломали). Изпользуйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку переменных. https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/wiki/Examples#prepared-statements

Comment: Ничего не надо оборачивать. Просто передайте в виде строки.

Comment: @Ainar-G дополнил суть проблемы в посте, все равно не удается передать без ошибки(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема не в го, а в курле. Конечно у вас всё получается, когда вы экранируете кавычки. Когда вы в шеле пишете `{"txt":"cheers"}`, шел понимает это как `{txt:cheers}`, что не является верным JSON'ом.

Почитайте [про экранирование](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html)!

Answer (score 0):

Очень многое зависит от того, как реализуется подключение к базе данных. Если используются стандартные средства, то можно просто передать json-строку аргументом.

```
package x

import (
    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq" // Postgres driver
)

// подключение к базе данных и так далее

func sendJSONString(db *sql.DB, js string) (err error) {
    _, err = db.Exec(`INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ($1)`, js)
    return
}
```

Смотрите также про [внедрение SQL кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), так же известное как *SQL Injection*.